# Have a common path with variables in different services

Tags: spring, spring-restcontroller, spring-rest

I have two interfaces with the annotation @RequestMapping:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/users")
    public interface UserRestService{}
```

and

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/clients")
public interface ClientRestService{}
```

They both have methods to manage users and clients.

I already defined the initial path with the property:

```
servlet:
    context-path: /api
```

Now, I want to define a common path with a path parameter /v1/tenant/{tenant}/, so the complete URL for the services will be :
/api/v1/tenant/{tenant}/users
/api/v1/tenant/{tenant}/clients

I already tried having those two interfaces extending a common interface and with an annotation but without luck.
How can I do this without define for each interface the complete path?

Answer (score 1):

You can define `/v1/tenant/{tenant}` as an entry in the properties file. Then, you can inject it like this:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("${my.common.path}/clients")`
public interface ClientRestService{}

@RestController
@RequestMapping("${my.common.path}/users")`
public interface UserRestService{}
```

Properties file:

```
my.common.path = /v1/tenant/{tenant}
```

Finally, to access that path variable inside a method from either controller, you can do this:

```
@GetMapping("/")
public String test(@PathVariable String tenant) {
        
        return tenant;
}
```